# GAE - When I deploy app does not function, but on localhost it works?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have coded a gae engine java mail api using app.

my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>mailapps</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <!--
    HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:

      <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
    asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:

      <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />

    With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
    stale session data. For details, see
    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
  -->

</appengine-web-app>
```

When I run the app on localhost I everything works well, but when I run deploy it on gae and run it I get:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request.
>
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

Whats wrong with my app? Can you please help me?

**1.UPDATE_**

gae logs say:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send
>   failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments
>   (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unauthorized Sender: Unauthorized
>   sender))

**2.UPDATE**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FeedbackServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FeedbackServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String description = req.getParameter("description");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        log.info(description + name + email + " :Daten extrahiert!");
        String msgBody = name  + " :Name der Person" + "\n" + description + " :Beschreibung der Person" + "\n" + email + " :EMAIL";

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mailapps@gmail.com",
                    "It works"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("maximus@gmail.com", "Your name"));
            msg.setSubject("Bestellung");
            msg.setText(msgBody);
            log.info("Message send!");
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(
                "Thanks you for your feedback. An Email has been send out.");
    }
}
```

Thats the servlet!

Comment: You may want to open the GAE log (in your GAE dashboard), and check if there's more useful info on the error

Comment: it says: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unauthorized Sender: Unauthorized sender))

Comment: You need to post JavaMail part of your application

Comment: I posted the servlet in UPDATE 2. I would appreaciate it if you would have a look at it!!!

Comment: @user1248720 Google App Engine has security restriction on Senders Email id. Have you read document??. Try Sendid same as your google account??

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer!!! So what do I have to change that it works? btw which document do you mean?

Comment: Try adding your own google account or add a new account from permissions, in admin console. instead of `mailapps@gmail.com` your own google account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does mailapps@gmail.com have permission to your application?

Answer (score 4):

There are clear restrictions for the sender Email Address. Google App Engine documentation has provided details on this.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Sending_Mail

and it will give you enough options that you can consider.

Answer (score 2):

In console go to **App Engine > Settings > Application Settings**. Add this email address to the list of authorised senders. This issue is appear because you are sending email from unauthorised email id .

- *It does not matter you are owner of the project or not you have to
  add the sender email id  in the application settings of app engine >>
  setting*

[image]